# Switching to open instance of file being edited with vim

Tags: vim

I often try to edit a file with Vim that is already open in another Vim instance.  In this case, you get the error dialog "Swap file "..." already exists!" with options Open Read-Only, Edit anyway, Recover, Quit, and Abort.

In almost all cases, what I would like to do is simply switch to the Vim instance that is already open, and continue editing it.  Instead, I have to close this attempt with Quit or Abort and then hunt for the open window of the other instance (which may be difficult if there are many open windows, some hidden, some on another workspace, etc.)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could work around this by setting up your environment to use Vim's client/server feature.

Aliasing `vim` to `vim --servername VIM --remote` may be enough to solve your "problem".

But I think you should probably revise your workflow and open related files from vim itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting the following line in your .bashrc file

```
alias vim='vim --remote-silent'
```

That way if the file is already open you won't get the annoying "Swap file..." message and if it is not already open you won't be shown an error.

Answer (score 0):

Install `wmctrl`, then you can write a script aliased to `vim` or `gvim` that looks in your /tmp directory for the existence of a swap file with the same name. If it exists, then you use wmctrl to bring the right window to the foreground, otherwise call vim/gvim as appropriate.